# Can I define setter and getter in the attribute itself, rather than the containing class?

Tags: dart, descriptor

Suppose I want my class to do things on attribute access. I can of course do that in setters and getters:

```dart
class Foo {
    set bar (v) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

However, if I want to attach the same behavior to multiple attributes, I'd have to explicitly define the same setters and getters for every one of them. (The use case I have in mind is an observable, i.e. a class that knows when its attributes are being changed).

What I'd like to do  is something like:

```dart
class Foo {
    var bar = new AttributeWithAccessBehavior();
}
```

Python does this with descriptors - what is the closest thing in Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't anything with getter/setter syntax that you can reuse.

You could assign a function to a field, that you can access using call notation `()`, but you have to be careful to call the function instead of overriding the field assignment.

A similar but more powerful alternative are classes that can emulate functions (see https://www.dartlang.org/articles/emulating-functions/)

A class that has a `call` method can be used like a method.
This is similar to assigned functions mentioned above but in addition you can store state information.

If you implement actual getter/setter you can of course delegate to whatever you want, but that is obviously not what you are looking for.

For the use case you mentioned, there is the `observe` package. 
I have no idea how exactly it solves the problem, but it works quite well.

Comment: `observe` does not really solve the problem - it requires you to either poll objects for changes, or define setters for your attributes.